# WinJS Enumeration

Tags: windows-8, winjs, windows-8.1

How can I make an enumeration in WinJS?

I tried to make a class like this for example:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

var TaskEnum = WinJS.Class.define(
null,
{},
// The set of static members.
{
    SUPERVISION: 1,
    DIG: 2,
    MAP: 3,
});


var Task = new TaskEnum();

WinJS.Namespace.define("ENUMS", {
    TASK: {
        get: function () {
            return Task;
        }
    }
});


})();
```

But when I call `ENUMS.TASK.DIG` then DIG is undefined.

I even tried just this:

```
WinJS.Namespace.define("ENUMS", {
    TASK:  { SUPERVISION: 1, DIG: 2, MAP: 3, }
});
```

But when I call `ENUMS.TASK.DIG` then DIG is still undefined.

It seems like the Namespace.define does not work in that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohk, If i get you exact then , you want to define `Enumeration` in JavaScript?
right ?
For this case I don't think if it is done with WinJs or not on `Windows Store App`,
but I have two Suggestions as my answer :

1 ) Use `C#` as [Runtime Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230301%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to perform This operations, by defining a function in c# and simply call it on your JavaScript.

[**See ,Creating a simple component in C#.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779077%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

2 ) [**Enumerated types in JavaScript**](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-9/enumerated-types-in-javascript)

Or See : **WinJS.UI Namespace**
`http://207.46.99.208/pl-pl/library/windows/apps/br229782#enums_section`

Comment: And if you are success in creating, WinJs Enumeration then ,dont forget to post your answer as well. @Maurizio In denmark

Comment: I think you may be right about the RT component. it seems like this is the way they do their own enums in WinJS

Comment: Ya,Right Mr @Maurizio In denmark, By adding thies  Runtime Component,you will definitively have the power to manipulate any data types with ease.

Answer (score 1):

I might not understand what you're hoping to get out of the `Namespace` definition, but not just use core JavaScript?

```
window.ENUMS = {
    TASK: {
        SUPERVISION: 1,
        DIG: 2,
        MAP: 3
    }
};
```

Then use it like you were trying to:

```
callSomeFunction(ENUMS.TASK.DIG);
```

Note that if you can restrict users to IE11 (not so difficult in Win8 apps) then you can make use of [JavaScript constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn251545%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) through `const` as well.

Comment: yes this is an easy and nice solution, but how do they do their enums in winjs? I had a look and canøt quite figure it out. they seems to make them in an RTcomponent, maybe in C#

Comment: JS doesn't really have a concept of enumerations. You can mimic one using an object like this. The WinJS class and namespace helpers aren't magic, they're just formalizations of common patterns that everyone uses.

I don't really understand why your WinJS.Namespace.define example wouldn't work. That's doing the same thing as attaching the TASK object to window/self, and should work just fine.

Comment: Oh, and no WinJS does not use C# or any WinRT components. The WinRT API surface itself (separate from WinJS) exposes enums using, well, the WinRT type system. WinJS enumerations are just JS object literals. Just look at the code, it's all there for you to see. For example, from base.js line 121 (WinJS 2.0):

        var LazyStates = {
            uninitialized: 1,
            working: 2,
            initialized: 3,
        };